# Display ArcGIS WMS in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wms

I would like to display a basic map of Brno in WMS format in the Leaflet. I'm trying to follow the documentation, but I have a problem about any display of data from this layer. Anyone idea what could be the problem? In QGIS the layer can be displayed normally.

https://gis.brno.cz/arcgis/rest/services/PUBLIC/basemap_brno_zakladni_mapa_seda_tiled/MapServer

```
 const map = L.map('map').setView([49, 16.5], 10);
 
  
  var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('https://gis.brno.cz/arcgis/services/PUBLIC/basemap_brno_zakladni_mapa_seda_tiled/MapServer/WMSServer?', {
    layers: "0",
    format: 'image/png32',

  }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a WMS service.

Comment: Having the [WMS docs](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html) in mind, maybe try accessing `https://gis.brno.cz/arcgis/services/PUBLIC/basemap_brno_zakladni_mapa_seda_tiled/MapServer/WMSServer?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities` instead? Your URL currently seems to point to the REST service.

Comment: Which of these maps https://gis.brno.cz/ you want to display?

Comment: If you want to use ArcGIS Rest Services in Leaflet, try this plugin: https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet.

Comment: .... because the URL you mentioned in your op is an ArcGIS Rest url. If you want to add an overlay to a basemap, use L.esri.dynamicMapLayer, like so:
var my_layer = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({
 url: your_url,
 layers: [12],
 f: "image"
}); 
the value in layers you can get from the first URL you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The WMS URL given is incorrect, it should be:

```
https://gis.brno.cz/arcgis/services/PUBLIC/basemap_brno_zakladni_mapa_seda_tiled/MapServer/WMSServer?
```

There is no layer `0` in the service

Many of the layers appear only at set scales See `MinScaleDenominator` and `MaxScaleDenominator` values in the GetCapabilities response (https://gis.brno.cz/arcgis/services/PUBLIC/basemap_brno_zakladni_mapa_seda_tiled/MapServer/WMSServer?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities)